# How to create jQuery object from array of jQuery objects?

Tags: arrays, jquery

Let's say I have an array of jQuery objects and wish to have one compound jQuery object instead.

What would be the solution other than manual traversing an array and appending the elements to the just created jquery object using `.add()`?

This doesn't do what I want:

```
var a = $('#a'),
    b = $('#b'),
    c = [a, b];

// the lines above is the set up, they cannot be changed
var d = $(c);
d.hide();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/896eN/1/

The expected result is both divs are hidden.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your fiddle seems to have an error; there is no element `#c`. Edit: in regards to your question I believe `add()` may be the only option. But I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @powerbuoy: yep, that was a typo, thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try

```
var d = $($.map(c, function(el){return $.makeArray(el)}));
```

Or

```
var d = $($.map(c, function(el){return el.get();}));
```

[***The demo.***](http://jsfiddle.net/896eN/3/)

Comment: Yep, what I thought of is `var d = $(c.map(function(el){ return el[0]; }));`. +1 because currently it is the only answer that answers the original question

Comment: `return el[0];` will only get the first element, if your selector matches multiple elements, the left element wont be in `d`.

Comment: right, didn't take it into account (most likely because I have only one element per object)

Comment: This seems super complicated. also I don't get it - why would you do $.makeArray(el) ?

Answer (score 19):

I came here looking for a cleaner answer than I already had, but didn't find one. For the sake of the next guy to come along I guess I'll post my solution instead:

```
var a = $('#a'),
    b = $('#b'),
    c = [a, b];

var d = c.reduce($.merge);
d.hide();​
```

I'm sort of surprised there isn't some `jQuery` specific method that makes this cleaner, but `Array.reduce` is definitely the correct tool for this job if nothing more specific exists in `jQuery`.

Comment: This seems way cleaner than the accepted answer to me.

Comment: This is a nice and clean solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you [try](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/896eN/4/)

```
var a = $('#a'),
b = $('#b'),
c = [a, b];
d = [];
$.each(c, function(i, v){
    if(v.length>0){
        d.push(v[0]);
    }
});

e = $(d);
e.hide();
```

Comment: I already have an array of objects. So `a,b,c` variables from the example cannot be changed

Comment: Then probably you can create another array d by iterating through `c`!

Comment: Yep. Now it does the work. Though creating jquery object and using `.add()` could be a bit better

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var a = $('#a'),
    b = $('#b'),
    c = [a, b],
    d = $();
$.each(c, function(i, jqObj) {
    $.merge(d, jqObj);
});
d.hide();
```

or:

```
var a = $('#a'),
    b = $('#b'),
    c = [a, b],
    d = $();
$.each(c, function(i, jqObj) {
    d = d.add(jqObj);
});
d.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var els = ['#a', '#b', '#c']
var $els = $(els.join(', '))
```

**Edit:** This will do, ugly tho:

```
var d = $(function(){
    var els = []
    for (var i = 0, l = c.length; i < l; i++)
        els.push(c[i][0])
    return els
}())
```

Comment: I don't have selectors, I have an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know that you have an array of jQuery objects, you can use `$.each` to cycle through them (or just treat them as a normal array to cycle through them).  You can use this to create a combined selector if you like, or just do operations on them in the iterator.

Comment: Yep, I can traverse them and what's next? This answer is not complete, as long as it doesn't say how exactly we get the jquery object as a result

Comment: @zerkms why do you need the jQuery object in particular as opposed to doing operations in the iteration?

Comment: because I need to pass the object in a next function, that assumes it is the single jquery object

Comment: @zerkms what is the function and why can't you pass them individually?

Comment: the function does `parameter.hide();` as it is in jsfiddle. And it is designed to accept jquery object specifically

Comment: @zerkms `$.each(arrayOfJquery, function () { $(this).hide(); });`

Comment: omg, that function is a "bit" more difficult than just `hide()`. You know of encapsulation? Well, some logic is encapsulated there, and I need to pass a jquery object because of a function interface.